# Awesome Icon selection list missing options

Tags: font-awesome

I have just downloaded and installed a new theme ( flat metro ). It uses the Font Awesome 4 Menu plugin which i have installed and is version 4.5.0.0

When creating a page there is a selection box to choose the font awesome icon, along with a link showing all icons available.

The problem is some of the icons are missing from the selection list. For example, i have no icons that start with "n". I did want to use the newspaper icon but i simply don't have it listed. There are several others that are also missing.

I can not see a way to update the list and the version is current, am i missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Try referencing the font-awesome CSS file from a CDN instead of a local copy if it exists. https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

Comment: Sorry, makes no difference, tried selecting "Official Font Awesome CDN " and also adding the URL you have provided to "A custom location:". In either case the list of available icons does not change. Do i have to do anything to update the list?

Comment: It would help if you posted your code.